# How to get the quarterly period from given year till current date in python?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy, datetime

I'm trying to get the quarterly period from given period till current date. I want the previous quarter of the current year e.g. 2021K4 not the current one. Following is the code I've used to get it.

```
import datetime
import json
from_year = 2018
last_year = datetime.datetime.now().year
year_list = list(range(from_year, last_year))
period = []
for all_year in year_list:
    all_months = [str(all_year)+'K'+str(i) for i in list(range(1,5))]
    period = period + all_months
quarter = json.dumps(period)
print(quarter)
```

Output - ["2018K1", "2018K2", "2018K3", "2018K4", "2019K1", "2019K2", "2019K3", "2019K4", "2020K1", "2020K2", "2020K3", "2020K4"]

Desired Output - ["2018K1", "2018K2", "2018K3", "2018K4", "2019K1", "2019K2", "2019K3", "2019K4", "2020K1", "2020K2", "2020K3", "2020K4","2021K1"]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the problem is when you are defining year_list

try doing this:

```
import datetime
import json
from_year = 2018
current_year = datetime.datetime.now().year
current_month = int(datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%m"))
year_list = list(range(from_year, current_year+1))
period = []
for all_year in year_list:
    if all_year != current_year:
        all_months = [str(all_year)+'K'+str(i) for i in list(range(1,5))]
        period += all_months        
    else:
        for q in range (1,((current_month-1)//3+1)):
            period.append(str(current_year)+'K'+str(q))
quarter = json.dumps(period)
print(quarter)
```

Comment: I'm getting this now ["2018K1", "2018K2", "2018K3", "2018K4", "2019K1", "2019K2", "2019K3", "2019K4", "2020K1", "2020K2", "2020K3", "2020K4", "2021K1", "2021K2", "2021K3", "2021K4"], But I need  ["2018K1", "2018K2", "2018K3", "2018K4", "2019K1", "2019K2", "2019K3", "2019K4", "2020K1", "2020K2", "2020K3", "2020K4", "2021K1"]

Comment: @SSS from what i understand you want to get values till last quarter of the current year, i.e. 2021K2, I have updated the code please take a look